# How to run Ansible without specifying the inventory but the host directly?

Tags: python, ansible

I want to run Ansible in Python without specifying the inventory file through (ANSIBLE_HOST) but just by:

```
ansible.run.Runner(
  module_name='ping',
  host='www.google.com'
)
```

I can actually do this in fabric easily but just wonder how to do this in Python. On the other hand, documentation of the Ansible API for python is not really complete.

Answer (score 225):

Surprisingly, the trick is to append a `,`

```
# Host and IP address
ansible all -i example.com,
ansible all -i 93.184.216.119,
```

or

```
# Requires 'hosts: all' in your playbook
ansible-playbook -i example.com, playbook.yml
```

The host parameter preceding the `,` can be either a hostname or an IPv4/v6 address.

Comment: In Ansible 1.9.1, when you call ansible-playbook remove "all" from the command line but leave it in the playbook.yml. This is the right answer "ansible-playbook -i example.com, playbook.yml"

Comment: Then, what should I set as "host" in the playbook so it works with any server?

Comment: @azmeuk in the playbook, "hosts: all" should work fine. I typically do that and then use -i or --limit on the command line to specify the hosts.

Comment: what if a playbook has two different stages with connections to different hosts/ips?  note I don't mean to run one sections againts multiple ip's, but to run 2 different sections against different ip's?

Comment: Probably not so surprisingly for Python programmers.

Answer (score 69):

I know this question is really old but think that this little trick might helpful for future users who need help for this:

```
ansible-playbook -i 10.254.3.133, site.yml
```

if you run for local host:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, --connection=local site.yml
```

The trick is that after ip address/dns name, put the comma inside the quotes and  requires '`hosts: all`' in your playbook.

Hope this will help.

Comment: For what it's worth, the quotes are a no-op here.  If you use `'localhost,'` or `localhost,`, in both cases `ansible-playbook` will receive the same argument from the shell.  And `'localhost',` would evaluate the same way (the key here is that quotes are interpreted by the shell before it passes the arguments to your command).

Comment: This works, but why in the name of Merlin's beard is this acceptable behaviour on ansible's part?! How exactly are people expected to know this? I tore my hair out looking for said fix.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I've just stumbled on your comment and wanted to offer some insight here.

The reason this works is because the -i flag requires you to pass a valid inventory target, which can be an INI file, an Ansible-valid inventory executable or any arbitrary string that can be handled by an Ansible inventory plugin.

There's an Ansible plugin named "host_list" which takes a lists of hosts separated by commas and uses that information to create an on-the-fly inventory to allow the execution of ad-hoc commands on unknown hosts.

This plugin is included by default on Ansible.

Comment: I feel it's a bit risky to have a playbook with `hosts: all` when I intend to run it on only one host at a time. A co-worker might run the playbook without `-i`. This is a nice solution, but I continue to look for something safer.  Still searching...

Comment: This works, but how to load the variables from the inventory? Previously I've used `-i live`, but now when switched to single IP I've no option of loading the vars from `live` folder.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I did not want to have `hosts: all` in my playbook, because it would be bad if someone ran the playbook and forgot to include `-i 10.254.3.133,`

This was my solution (ansible 2.6):

```
$ ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -e "{target: 10.1.1.1}" -i 10.1.1.1, ...
```

And then, in the playbook:

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  remote_user: donn
  vars_files:
    - myvars
  roles:
    - myrole
```

This is a special use-case when I need to provision a host and I don't want/need to add it to the inventory.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with:

```
hosts = ["webserver1","webserver2"]

webInventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(hosts)

webPing = ansible.runner.Runner(
    pattern='webserver*',
    module_name='ping',
    inventory = webInventory
).run()
```

Whatever is in hosts becomes your inventory and you can search it with pattern (or do "all").

Comment: do you know how to run module in local_action context, for example ec2 modules should be invoked agains localhost (127.0.0.1) and as local_action. thanks

Comment: nevermind, I answer my own question :-) 

runner = ansible.Runner(
                module_name="ec2_group",
                complex_args={},
                forks=paralel,
                # private_key_file="~/.ssh/office.pem",
                inventory=Inventory(["127.0.0.1"]),
                transport="local"
            )
            return runner.run()

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to drive the [Ansible Python API](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html), and would rather pass hosts as arguments rather than keep an inventory. I used a temporary file to get around Ansible's requirement, which may be helpful to others:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.runner import Runner

def load_temporary_inventory(content):
    tmpfile = NamedTemporaryFile()
    try:
        tmpfile.write(content)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        inventory = Inventory(tmpfile.name)
    finally:
        tmpfile.close()
    return inventory

def ping(hostname):
    inventory = load_temporary_inventory(hostname)
    runner = Runner(
        module_name='ping',
        inventory=inventory,
    )
    return runner.run()
```

Comment: can you also give an example that how you are using it

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution as per my understanding, apologize if it's a distraction.

Here are 3 main steps needs to be there,

1. command-line options
2. What needs to be exposed in the playbook.yml
3. What it says

### 1.command-line options

ansible-playbook -l "host-name" <playbook.yml>

**Please note that host-name is $hostname of the node**

### 2.What needs to be exposed inside the playbook.yml

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['webservers']
```

### 3.What it says? Have a look   :)

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 10 December 2020  13:01:07 +0530 (0:00:03.153)       0:00:03.363 *****
ok: [node1] => {
    "msg": "192.168.1.186"
}
```

This is how we can execute tasks on specific nodes using the **--limit or -l** option