# Ansible include_vars continue if file not found

Tags: ansible

If I have something like this:

```
- include_vars: this_file_doesnt_exist.yml
```

ansible will throw the error "input file not found at ..." and stop the provisioning process.

I'm wondering if it's possible to **allow the provisioning process to continue if the file isn't found**.

My use case is the following:

- try to load variables file
- execute tasks if those variables exist

Example:

```
- include_vars: aptcacher.yml

- name: use apt-cache
  template: src=01_proxy.j2 dest=/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01_proxy owner=root group=root mode=644
  sudo: true
  when: aptcacher_host is defined
```

Ansible version: 1.9.1

Answer (score 5):

You can just `ignore_errors` on the `include_vars` task:

```
- include_vars: nonexistant_file
  ignore_errors: yes
```

**EDIT**

With ansible > 1.6.5 I am getting

test.yml

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: nonexistent_file
      ignore_errors: yes

    - debug:
        msg="The show goes on"
```

> PLAY [localhost]
>
> ---
>
> GATHERING FACTS
>   ***************************************************************  ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK: [include_vars nonexistent_file]
>   *****************************************  failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "file":
>   "/home/ilya/spielwiese/ansible/nonexistent_file"} msg: Source file not
>   found. ...ignoring
>
> TASK: [debug msg="The show goes on"]
>   ******************************************  ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "The show goes on" }

Comment: I've tried with "ignore_errors" but doesn't seem to work. Ansible will throw the same error "input file not found at ...". Thanks

Comment: You are using `include_vars` as task? Have you tried the playbook as i posted above?

Comment: Just tried your playbook (`ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml`) and got the same error "input file not found at ...". Are you using a different command to run your playbook? I'm using ansible 1.9.1.

Comment: Oh, this is totally not the way ansible is called (just wondering that anything else works with you) . You need to specify an inventory file with -i (and there should be **no** comma. So the call goes like that `ansible-playbook test.yml` or `ansible-playbook -i /path/to/inventory test.yml`

Comment: and your inventory file should contain something like `localhost ansible_connection=local` (see documentation)

Comment: There's a reason for invoking ansible that way: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188147/how-to-run-ansible-without-specifying-the-inventory-but-the-host-directly), [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9932) or search google "how to run ansible without inventory". Either way it doesn't work. Regarding "if anything else works with me": yes, except this part. My suspicions for now are the different versions. Thanks

Comment: Got it tested with 1.9.1 . Please try this call `ansible-playbook -e ansible_connection=local -i localhost, test.yml` . I suspect that you maybe did not pass the ansible_local variable to the localhost connection. (If i don't, i get the same error). The call mentioned above works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`with_first_found`](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#selecting-files-and-templates-based-on-variables) to archive this.

```
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
   - this_file_doesnt_exist.yml
```

I'm not 100% sure it will work without complain if not at least one file matched. In case it doesn't work, you will need to add an empty fallback file:

```
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
   - this_file_doesnt_exist.yml
   - empty_falback.yml
```

Comment: The first case doesn't work, it needs at least one file matched (outputs "No source file given"). The second case indeed works, but it sounds more like a workaround rather a proper/clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To optionally include variables, you can use the `with_first_found` loop which is based on the [`ansible.builtin.first_found`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html) lookup. With `skip: true`, you can assert that it does not error, when it does not find any files:

```yaml
- include_vars: '{{ item }}'
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - this_file_doesnt_exist.yml
      skip: true
```

---

From Ansible 2.2 on, you can also use a regex pattern for files to include. The module will not error if it does not find any files. Caveat: You have to provide a directory name, that *does* exist:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    dir: vars
    files_matching: this_file_doesnt_exist.yml
```