# How do I access the argument as inventory in a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm passing the IP as parameter as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18255256/1784001

```
ansible-playbook roles/example/main.yml -i 127.0.0.1,
```

Is there any way to access the value for the inventory parameter, "127.0.0.1" in a **playbook**?
I checked the special variables, but I see no mention of it: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

In some of the tasks I need that value, for example creating backup directories, or scp-ing to the host.

Answer (score 0):

[inventory_hostname](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) always contains the inventory hostname of the host the play is running at.

The parameter -i "`specify inventory host path or comma separated host list.`" Running the playbook main.yml

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

With the command

```
$ ansible-playbook -i 127.0.0.1,  main.yml
```

gives

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => 
  inventory_hostname: 127.0.0.1
```